# HOW to display javascript output in a html textbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a script that helps to calculate working days between two  days with JavaScript but i want to send the output to a MySQL database.
Like the value at the end of the code "dif" that outputs in the span to be writing to a mysql database or if i can place it in a text box and eventually post it to database

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head><body>
<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#calc').click(() => {
  var d1 = $('#d1').val();
  var d2 = $('#d2').val();
    $('#dif').text(workingDaysBetweenDates(d1,d2));
  });
});

let workingDaysBetweenDates = (d0, d1) => {
  /* Two working days and an sunday (not working day) */
  var holidays = ['2020/04/06', '2020/06/04', '06/04/2020','04/06/2020'];
  var startDate = parseDate(d0);
  var endDate = parseDate(d1);  

// Validate input
  if (endDate < startDate) {
    return 0;
  }

// Calculate days between dates
  var millisecondsPerDay = 86400 * 1000; // Day in milliseconds
  startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 1);  // Start just after midnight
  endDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);  // End just before midnight
  var diff = endDate - startDate;  // Milliseconds between datetime objects    
  var days = Math.ceil(diff / millisecondsPerDay);

  // Subtract two weekend days for every week in between
  var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
  days -= weeks * 2;

  // Handle special cases
  var startDay = startDate.getDay();
  var endDay = endDate.getDay();
    
  // Remove weekend not previously removed.   
  if (startDay - endDay > 1) {
    days -= 2;
  }
  // Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
  if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6) {
    days--;  
  }
  // Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
  if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0) {
    days--;
  }
  /* Here is the code */
  holidays.forEach(day => {
    if ((day >= d0) && (day <= d1)) {
      /* If it is not saturday (6) or sunday (0), substract it */
      if ((parseDate(day).getDay() % 6) != 0) {
        days--;
      }
    }
  });
  return days;
}
           
function parseDate(input) {
 // Transform date from text to date
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  // new Date(year, month [, date [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); // months are 0-based
}
</script>
<input type="date" id="d1" value="06/06/2020"><br>
<input type="date" id="d2" value="05/06/2020">

<p>Working days count: <span id="dif"></span></p>
<button id="calc">Calc</button>
</body>
</html>
```

database please help here is the script.

Answer (score 0):

To send any data to a database, you'll need to utilize a POST request to your server. To do this, you'll want to wrap whatever it is you plan on sending to the database (in your case, the dif) in an HTML form element. Inside the form element, store that dif variable as a value of an input element (you can hide this element if you wish), then use an AJAX call or a HTTP Request to send that data to the server.

For more information on how to apply this to your situation, check out this quick little [rundown](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)

Comment: thanks for your comment. i think my question was kind of ambiguous. What i want is how to place that variable diff in a textbox. i guess from there i can now manipulate as i choose to

Comment: No worries! Here is an example that should work for you: 
<input type = 'text' id = 'someID' name = 'thisNameWillBeSentToTheServer'></input>

JS:
var text = document.getElementById('someID').value = dif;

Comment: Thanks man. That has shown a green light on the job. But It changed the text box value to [object HTML spanElement]  and not the text on the span. Please help me check again thanks